# How to get image path Uri and Crop for all devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-library

I have my main project which gets images from certain sources (returns Uri). The next step was to crop the image to scale (touch input). I recently found out that some phone manufacturer mess around with the android base classes so:

```
com.android.camera.action.crop
```

doesn't always exist.

So I've found a library that does cropping: https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage
I've added the library into my eclipse build path and project library's.

my question is, can I open the library like so:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");  
    //intent.setClassName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CropImage"); 
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("output", Uri); 
    intent.putExtra("outputFormat", "JPEG");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

And then retrieve the cropped image or do I have to do something else extra?

1. Another question: Also will this effect my app when I put it onto market (will the user need to download or accept permission for the extra library?

I want to make sure that my app works on everything, so is this the best way of doing it? Or is there better methods, please explain. (Also keep it simple, fairly new to Android dev!, thanks!)

Comment: "I recently found out that some phone manufacturer mess around with the android base classes so: com.android.camera.action.crop doesn't always exist" -- that is not an "Android base class". Nobody should be expecting it, or anything else in `com.android`, to "always exist".

Comment: Ok so it's good practice to include these library's? Am I doing this right? I've never used another library in my projects before, always just created everything from scratch, but now I'm pushed for time I don't have the time to create crop-scale class from scratch. Can you give me some advice?

Comment: "so it's good practice to include these library's?" -- open source Android library projects can be useful. I publish a number of them myself. I have never used this specific library, so I cannot comment on how you integrate it. Unfortunately, the author of the library did not include a sample app demonstrating how to use it.

Comment: Can I simply include it within the build path and call upon the classes or will this fail?

Comment: Read the following pages: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#ReferencingLibraryProject (the last one is for command-line builds, if that's what you are doing). These are the instructions from the Developer Guide for how to use an Android library project.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Just one more thing, does the code look right for opening this library (generally looking right) or is there another way to open a library class?

Comment: From what I read in the project's README, what you have seems plausible. However, I would describe it as "non-traditional". More library projects will expose classes and methods than only exposing activities.

Comment: I already know the Uri is it possible to input this into this intent? putExtra("Uri", uri)?

Comment: Please contact the author of the library for further support.

Comment: You can do what I said, working fine and dandy on all devices. Awesome thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I installed the library and made sure it was linking to my project and was in the build path, then I simply did:

Open file manager:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
```

Alternatively if you want to capture from camera

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, GET_IMAGE_FROM_CAMERA);
```

Then crop image:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.android.camera.CropImage.class);
    intent.setData(uri);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CROP);
```

I've tested this on a few devices and it's working fine and dandy. Also works with camera.

Comment: Olly Dixon i am capturing image from camera and your solution does not work for me..i am using neo v..